# What is the equivalent of OCaml's modules in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, module, ocaml

Most of the Haskell code I see make use of direct structures such as lists and trees. For example, it is common for a Haskeller to write:

```
fillRect :: Color → Bounds → Image → Image
```

That pattern has a problem: if later on the programmer decides to modify the definition of "Image", or use another data-structure, then he will have to **refactor every single piece of code using it**. In OCaml, you can simply use a module specifying an interface to an Image, and then decide upon specific implementations later on.

What is the Haskell alternative to OCaml's modules?

Comment: How does that type signature mean that `fillRect` uses (or even has access to) implementation details of the `Image` type? How would you write that signature differently in OCaml (other than the obvious syntactic differences and the different naming conventions)?

Comment: [This is the Haskell analog](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) of what you describe.  It's not as powerful as Ocaml modules (at least, not without a lot of extensions), but it covers most common use cases.  Just make the record of functions polymorphic over the type that supports those operations.

Comment: Backpack is an effort to get some form of module into Haskell - http://plv.mpi-sws.org/backpack/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several alternatives; none exactly matches ML modules, but each some aspect.

- Parametric polymorphism. Rather than parameterising your module and the `fillRect` function therein on `Image`, you parameterise the abstract `Image` type<sup><sub>-constructor</sub></sup> on something that specifies the particular "kind" of image. So that would be a signature like

  ```hs
  fillRect_ppm :: ImageImplemetation i => Colour -> Bounds -> Image i -> Image i
  ```

  where `ImageImplemetation` is some type class that specifies something like conversion and/or backend functions.
  With such a solution, you can't really *replace* the `Image` type completely, but you can make the type itself arbitrarily flexible. Likely, all concrete types you'll be using for `Image` will actually share some fields, so it's better not to make it more flexible than necessary: different instances of `ImageImplemetation` just need to implement what's *different* between them. If the implementations are very similar, perhaps you want to parameterise on just some detail like the colour space.

  Of course you need to plan ahead quite a bit with this solution, but just for a common interface. You can still put in *any* type as the argument later, provided you define the necessary instances.
- Similarly (and possible to mix), you could just have a type class for *types that can hold image data*.

  ```hs
  fillRect_tcl :: Image img => Colour -> Bounds -> img -> img
  ```

  The `Image` class would directly define some primitives like how to draw lines, and `fillRect_tcl` would use these in its implementation. Good because `fillRect_tcl` works right away with any such type. What's a bit bad is that the `Image` class will need to be rather awkwardly big (it's *preferred* to use type classes for "mathematical" stuff with simple and very clear laws).

  - Perhaps the class could even have rectangles as a method:

    ```hs
    class Image img where
      ...
      fillRect_tcm :: Colour -> Bounds -> img -> img
      ...
    ```

    not so nice is, you'll need to completely re-define that method for any `img` instance.
- Haskell's module system can't do a lot, but still it's sometimes enough to save you from *refactoring everything*. For instance, if `Image` came from a module `Data.Image`, you could have done

  ```hs
  import qualified Data.Image as IM

  fillRect_qfi :: Colour -> Bounds -> IM.Image -> IM.Image
  ```

  and use all functions defined in that module, also by qualifier. If at some point you decide to switch implementation, you can just change the import.
  Of course this isn't much good for *switching* between types on a regular basis, but quite ok for one-time changes.

Quite fitting to your example: [diagrams](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib) uses both the first points; e.g. [rect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/diagrams-lib-1.2.0.3/docs/Diagrams-TwoD-Shapes.html#v:rect) uses a `TrailLike` class to implement its primitives, and this class includes as "final" diagrams type `QDiagram`, which is parameterised on the backend you'll use for rendering.